# How to write a common event for all buttons in YUI3?

Tags: events, click, yui

As question describe all, but just for clarification, I want to do a common stuff like alert
value when i **click** on any button.

Please suggest a solution in YUI3 only because i am using YUI3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a more efficient way to do it:

```
Y.delegate('click', function(e) { ... }, 'body', 'button');
```

This attaches a single event handler to the body instead of attaching a separate event handler to each button.

[YUI Documentation - delegation](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event/#delegation)

Comment: John, I am novice in YUI and javascript so could you please clarify this line "This attaches a single event handler to the body instead of attaching a separate event handler to each button."?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want, you want to bind every button to the same event? Like say a user clicks any button you want to catch it? If so here is how it's done.

```
Y.all('button').on('click', function(e){
//handle event here
//e.preventDefault(); if needed to prevent default browser behavior 
});
```

This could be bound to any event for more details on events [YUI Events](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event/) should be useful. Hope this helps.